# Change all words in file greater than min and less then max to uppercase AWK

Tags: awk

> I need an awk script that replaces to uppercase all the words longer
>   than MIN, but shorter than MAX characters in a text file. The
>   parameters MIN and MAX must be passed to the script.

I even dont know how to read file word by word in awk. Can you help me pls?
I look everywhere and nothing helpful

Comment: Apparently you didn't look in the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins as there's PLENTY of helpful text in that. I can't believe you got 2 answers with no sample input, expected output, nor any attempt to solve it yourself, nor even a description of what a "word" is to you (for example in POSIX a hyphen is considered a word-constituent character, is it to you? Is `that's` one word or 2?). Must be a full moon....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the input `test.txt`:

```
I need an awk script that replaces to uppercase all the words longer than MIN, 
but shorter than MAX characters in a text file.
The parameters MIN and MAX must be passed to the script.
```

This script:

```
awk -F"[^a-zA-Z]" 'BEGIN{min=3;max=5}
               {for(i=1; i<=NF; i++){
                    if(length($i)>min && length($i)<max){
                          $i=toupper($i)
                    }
               }print $0}' test.txt
```

outputs:

```
I NEED an awk script THAT replaces to uppercase all the words longer THAN MIN  
but shorter THAN MAX characters in a TEXT FILE 
The parameters MIN and MAX MUST be passed to the script
```

If you want to pass the boundaries as parameters, do something like this:

```
min=3
max=5
awk -v min=$min -v max=$max -F"[^a-zA-Z]" '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++){
                    if(length($i)>min && length($i)<max){
                          $i=toupper($i)
                    }
               }print $0}' test.txt
```

**Update**
Thanks to the helpful comments of karakfa & glenn jackman a better solution (which does not discard punctuations such as ,.? etc. at the and of a word) might look like this:

```
min=3
max=5
awk -v min=$min -v max=$max '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
                    len = length($i)-(match($i, "[[:punct:]]")!=0?1:0);
                    if(len>min && len<max) $i=toupper($i)                       
               } print $0}' test.txt
```

This script, for instance, converts `Hey, Tony!` in `Hey, TONY!`

Comment: That's a clever solution, but it will translate **all** non-alpha characters to spaces

Comment: @karakfa: I have added a modified solution to my answer. Thanks!

Comment: @glennjackman: I have added a modified solution to my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Does it *need* to be awk?

```
env min=4 max=7 perl -pe 's/\b(\w{$ENV{min},$ENV{max}})\b/\U$1/g' filename
```